# How can I extend the richtextbox control using system namespace only

Tags: c#

Is there a way to extend the richtextbox control in c# using an equivalent method like below :

```
namespace System
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string PadBoth(this string str, int length)
        {
            int spaces = length - str.Length;
            int padLeft = spaces / 2 + str.Length;
            return str.PadLeft(padLeft).PadRight(length);
        }
    }
}
```

So something like :

```
namespace System.Windows.Controls
{
    public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
    {
        public static string MyCustomMethod()
        {
             return "It works!";
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to extend it using the old way by creating a class and inheriting the richtextbox object, however what I would prefer to do is the reverse as the above adds the functionality to the base RichTextBox object without the need to create a new custom usercontrol to extend it's functionality.

To be clear, I am **not** looking to do the following (or similar) :

```
public class Foo : RichTextBox { }
```

I am not sure what this method of extending is called or if it even has a specific name / classification, but it just feels more natural when objects are extended in this manner than creating new controls filling up an already bloated toolbar of hundreds of controls.

Comment: What you showed is an "extension method" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). The answer depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), for instance, this method will extend the RichTextBox:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void MyCustomMethod(this RichTextBox self)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It works, this textbox has " + self.Text + " as the text!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You wouldn't happen to know what namespace i should use, or does that go under `System` as well.

Comment: @SanuelJackson : As I mentioned in my answer: There is no specific namespace. Use your project's if you don't want anything else.

Comment: What @VisualVincent said is correct, the namespace doesn't matter.  You can use extension methods from any namespace, so I tend to create a new namespace for them and bring them into my code as I need them.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you  :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do like your string extension, but use a `RichTextBox` as the first argument:

```
public static string MyCustomMethod(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    return richTextBox.Text;
}
```

Also you don't need to have the same namespace as the control, you can use your own/your project's namespace without a problem.